# Parse each line in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, post, textarea

I want to create like a notepad in js and php
but I want it to add some spaces for each new line
I thought I can make it with a textarea, but I dont know how to
This is my idea:

```
<textarea name="text"></textarea>
```

and in PHP

```
$text = trim($_POST['text']);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
$textAr = array_filter($text, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind

foreach ($textAr as $line) {
    $height = $height + $line_height; 
}
```

But not really sure it works. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically discarding the `explode` step. Try this instead:

```
$textAr = array_filter(preg_split("/[\r\n]+/",$_POST['text']));
```

This basically allows any format of newline, and removes empty lines. You can then pass `$textAr` through `foreach`.

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>.../b> on line <b>190</b><br />

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my brain is already sleeping, but did you maybe mean

```
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$textAr = array_filter($text, 'trim'); seems to be wrong.
```

1. You use `$text` while you already have `$textAr` and want use it
2. Seems you need `array_map`, not `array_filter`

[array_map Manual](http://php.net/array_map)